# Hundreds of TCP connections opened by sqlservr.exe

Tags: hibernate, sql-server-2008-r2, tomcat7, c3p0

We have Tomcat on one machine and SQL Server on another.

Our SQL Server machine is Windows 2008 R2 64bit machine with 32GB usable RAM
4 processors, 16 cpus.
We use database pooling to keep db connection reusable.

I am looking at the Resource Monitor in `Task Manager` and I noticed hundrerds of TCP connections from application server to `SQL Server machine`.

There are 1014 total connections.

1009 of them are '*AWAITING COMMAND*', status = '*sleeping*'. 
Other 5 are '*SELECT*' and '*UPDATE*', status = '*runnable*'.

[image]
Does anyone know why is this happening?

My application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">4</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">25</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

c3p0.properties:

```
c3p0.maxIdleTime=900
c3p0.maxStatements=150
c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections=300
numHelperThreads=6
unreturnedConnectionTimeout=3600
```

Tomcat's context.xml:

```
<Resource 
    auth="Container" 
    description="MY Database" 
    driverClass="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
    name="jdbc/myDB" 
    username="sa" 
    password="p@ssword"
    type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://100.00.22.012:1433/mtDB;user=sa;password=p@ssword;TDS=8.0" "
  />
```

Comment: Has that machine been up for ~450 days?

Comment: Looks like both machines have been rebooted yesterday at 3am.

Comment: ok (there is a tcp/ip bug that keeps connections open after ~450 days on unpatched win2k8)